# Read SQL procedure from script file, Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

How can I read a stored procedure from a .sql file? Example of this file's content:

```
create or replace procedure insert(p_t varchar(20), p_e varchar(10), out p_id number)
as begin
insert into instrument(type, status) values (p_t, p_e);
commit;
select max(id) from instrument into p_id;
end /

...other procedures...
```

I want this procedure to be created when I use the command @"*filepath*", but instead of doing so, Oracle executes the content of the procedure.

I would like to create all my procedures reading the file I made, any ideas?.

Comment: Are you using SQL*Plus or some other tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, please don't call your procedure `INSERT`. I'd be horrified if this actually compiled.

Secondly, you seem to be missing a semi-colon after `end;` and you need to put the `/` on a new line:

```
create or replace procedure insert_instrument (
   p_t varchar(20), p_e varchar(10), out p_id number ) as 

begin
  insert into instrument(type, status) values (p_t, p_e);
  commit;
  select max(id) from instrument into p_id;
end;
 /
```

You could simplify this using the [RETURNING INTO](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/returninginto_clause.htm#LNPLS01354) clause; it saves an extra SELECT and so will operate quicker:

```
create or replace procedure insert_instrument (
   p_t varchar(20), p_e varchar(10), out p_id number ) as 

begin
  insert into instrument(type, status) 
  values (p_t, p_e)
  returning id into p_id;
  commit;
end;
 /
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the procedure name was just a typo:D I had already fixed it but your "returning into" suggestion is very much appreciated. Would like to clarify if you meant to use 'returning id into p_id'